# Pinned tabs show the Stack Exchange logo on Chrome but not on Safari

Tags: bug, logo, safari

I use Safari Version 10.0.2 (12602.3.12) and Chrome Version 55.0.2883.75 (64-bit) on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 Beta (16C53a).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What OS? And what browser versions?